# How to re-write this Common Lisp macro avoiding the back-quote notation?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, lisp-macros

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

In the last chapter, on Macros, the author presents examples to re-write the built-in `incf` macro. He teaches the concept with two different approaches: using back-quote notation and without it. Such as:

```lisp
(defmacro list-notation-my-incf (x)
  (list 'setq x (list '+ x 1)))

(defmacro backquote-notation-my-incf (x)
  `(setq ,x (+ ,x 1)))
```

Later, the author introduces another example:

> In the example below, TWO-FROM-ONE is a macro that takes a function
> name and another object as arguments; it expands into a call to the
> function with two arguments, both of which are the quoted object.

He only uses back-quote character to do it:

```lisp
(defmacro two-from-one (func object)
  `(,func ',object ',object))
```

And it works as expected:

```
CL-USER> (two-from-one cons stack-overflow)
(STACK-OVERFLOW . STACK-OVERFLOW)
```

Using `slime-macroexpad-1`, I have:

```lisp
(CONS 'STACK-OVERFLOW 'STACK-OVERFLOW)
```

As an exercise that **I created for myself**, I tried doing the same, but avoiding the back-quote notation. Unfortunately, I could not make it work:

```lisp
(defmacro list-two-from-one (func object)
  (list func (quote object) (quote object)))
```

Slime throws the error:

```lisp
The variable OBJECT is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

Doing a macro expansion, I see:

```lisp
(CONS OBJECT OBJECT)
```

If I try a different approach, it seems to be closer, but it does not work either:

```lisp
(defmacro list-two-from-one (func object)
  (list func object object))
```

Throws the error:

```lisp
The variable STACK-OVERFLOW is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

And, finally, the macro expansion indicates:

```lisp
(CONS STACK-OVERFLOW STACK-OVERFLOW)
```

I feel stuck. How do I successfully re-write the macro without using back-quote notation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like

```
(defmacro list-two-from-one (func object)
  (list func (list 'quote object) (list 'quote object)))
```

basically, the body of a macro should return the code, that, *when evaluated*, produces the desired result.

I.e., the macro body should produce `(CONS 'STACK-OVERFLOW 'STACK-OVERFLOW)`.

Since `'a` is the same as `(quote a)`, you want your macro to produce

```
(CONS (QUOTE STACK-OVERFLOW) (QUOTE STACK-OVERFLOW))
```

which is what my `defmacro` above returns.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro should expand to:

```
CL-USER 10 > (macroexpand '(two-from-one2 cons stack-overflow))
(CONS (QUOTE STACK-OVERFLOW) (QUOTE STACK-OVERFLOW))
```

So create lists with `quote` like this:

```
(defmacro two-from-one2 (func object)
  (list func (list 'quote object) (list 'quote object)))
```

Test:

```
CL-USER 9 > (two-from-one2 cons stack-overflow)
(STACK-OVERFLOW . STACK-OVERFLOW)
```